# How to select number of dimensions in t-SNE algorithm

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, visualization, pca, dimensionality-reduction

For PCA we can see variance_score and say how much percentage of original data variance is included in each Principal Components. With these variance scores, we can plot an elbow graph and decide the dimension for visualising data. But for t-SNE, I couldnt find any.
Is there any way to decide the number of dimensions in t-SNE?

Comment: It's one of the parameters you can define in the function if you are using `sklearn.manifold.TSNE`. tSNE dimensions don't work exactly like PCA dimensions however. The idea of "variance explained" doesn't really translate.

Comment: https://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/

Answer (score 0):

Use the [n_components](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html) parameter in the object construction.  If you're using a large dataset, [UMAP](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameters.html#n-components) scales better at reducing into multiple dimensions than tSNE.